# How to get the Custom flag for a Language using Language Code in WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I am using WPML for multilingual functionality.
I want to display the Language Name and Language Flag based on the Language code. I can get the Language Name using the below filter.
Here I have used 'de' as an example. This can be any other Language code.

```
$lang_code = 'de';
$lang_name = apply_filters('wpml_translated_language_name', false, $lang_code );
```

However, I am not able to retrieve the Flag associated with that language. I found an option to get the Flag using the below code but the issue is that it doesn't work if Custom Flag is configured for the language in the backend.

```
$flag_url = ICL_PLUGIN_URL . '/res/flags/' . $lang_code . '.svg';
```

I more thing is I don't want to use any hooks which loops through all the available languages to get the flag for 1 language as it is not the efficient way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is [hook](https://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/wpml-hooks-reference/#hook-602887) called `wpml_active_languages`, whose returned array includes for every language value `country_flag_url`. So you should be able to get url by something like code below:

```
$languages = apply_filters( 'wpml_active_languages', NULL, 'orderby=id&order=desc' );
$lang_code = 'de';
if (isset($languages[$lang_code]) && isset($languages[$lang_code]['country_flag_url'])) {
    $country_flag_url = $languages[$lang_code]['country_flag_url'];
    echo $country_flag_url;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I don't want to loop through all languages to get the flag for 1 language. 
Is this the efficient way to go about this?

Comment: @Rajeev did you find any (more) efficient way how to do it? I didn't find anything more elegant.

Comment: No luck. I am still looking for a better and a simpler solution. My website has a lot of languages so don't want to run through a loop.